# Am I right with this proof?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that, if  ∈ Z , then, $$(9^{2} + 6 + 2)^{1/2} $$ is irrational

Assume  $(9^{2} + 6 + 2)^{1/2} $ is rational then

$(9^{2} + 6 + 2)^{1/2}=m $ ,    m ∈ Z

$(9^{2} + 6 + 2)=m^{2} $

$(3n+1)^{2}+1=m^{2}$

$(3n+1)^{2}=m^{2}-1$

$(3n+1)^{2}=(m-1)(m+1)$

if m=1 then n=-1/3, which is a contradiction to  ∈ Z.

Comment: All that you have proved is that $\sqrt{9n^2+6n+1}$ is never equal to $1$.

Comment: & what if $m\ne 1? $...........

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$1=m^2-(3n+1)^2=(m+3n+1)(m-3n-1)$$

$m+3n+1=m-3n-1=\pm1$

Comment: it means that n=1/3 and it is a contradiction to  ∈ Z, am I right ? Was my proof wrong ?

Comment: @KingJames, Why $m$ has to be $1?$

Comment: $6n+2$ is their difference and it must equal to 0. this then implies that $n=-(1/3)$ note the negative sign.

Comment: why diff should be 0?

Comment: because if they are the same that's their difference, otherwise, your assumption means nothing. if their difference is 2 then $6n+2=2\implies n=0$ and a difference of negative 2 leads to $6n+2=-2\implies 6n=-4\implies n=-{2\over 3}$

Comment: it means that n=1/3 and it is a contradiction to  ∈ Z, am I right ?

Comment: @KingJames, correct